# Control if a series of strings contains a series of combinations of sub-strings in VB.NET

Tags: string, vb.net, parsing, string-comparison

:)

I have this situation: I have a List of objects defined by me, everyone with a String field in addition to some other data field. I have to verify, for each object, if this string field contains a series of combinations of sub-strings, doesn't contain, or partially contains them. So I've made a very long list of If instructions (not Select Case because a combination of sub-strings doesn't exclude any other) and now I have a very bad looking code in my opinion, kind of:

```
For Each art As Article In ArticlesList

If (((InStr(1, art.description, "string1") > 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string2") > 0)) Or ((InStr(1, art.description, "string3") > 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string4") > 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string8") > 0))) Then

'...do something

End if


If (((InStr(1, art.description, "string4") > 0)) Or ((InStr(1, art.description, "string3") = 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string5") = 0) Or (InStr(1, art.description, "string9") > 0))) Then

'...do something

End if
'...
'...
'...
'... many other If (about 80 or more)

Next
```

So, overall I'd like to ask a method to make a better-looking and more efficient code. In particular I'd like to limit the Instr() occurrences and I think would be better if I put these boolean conditions in some array or List and parse them in boolean expressions when needed, scrolling the list of strings and the one with boolean conditions together, but for example I can't put in a string the condition

```
Dim condition as String = "((InStr(1, art.description, "string1") > 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string2") > 0)) Or ((InStr(1, art.description, "string3") > 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string4") > 0) And (InStr(1, art.description, "string7") > 0))"
```

because Visual Studio says that "is expected the end of instruction" on "string1". But anyway, there are many conditions of various complexity, and I think the default parser functions will not work, also cause I'm trying to convert in strings a series of boolean conditions which are about strings comparisons.

Hope in some tips and suggestions.

Comment: sub strings of what???  `Manhattan` will always contain `hat`, tan` and `man`.  Also explore the Wonderful world of NET methods such as  `String.Contains()`, `.IndexOf()` and `.SubString()`.  And as always for those who havent, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: yes, I've seen these functions, but their occurrences would be the same as my Instr() if I use this logic, so I'd have to replace Instr() with them to get a better written code. If you read the question, I'm here first for get some tips about the logic  I'm using to make these operations, meaning that, maybe, there are ways a lot better which implies the knowledge of constructs that I would not even mind in trying, or search, to solve this problem, and that would make all Instr() replacements a waste of time. Got it? Anyway, now I will read the 'How to Ask' section, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @Plutonix said, using the .Contains(), .IndexOf() and .Substring() methods will make your code a lot cleaner. Also, not sure what you're trying to do in the last paragraph but if you want to put double quotes in a string, you have to use 2.

Example:

```
Dim condition As String = "((InStr(1, art.description, ""string1"") > 0)"
```

Comment: yes, I was just searching for a way to put quotes in strings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A few things. First you can put the strings you are trying to find in an array and use `Any`:

```
If {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string8"}.Any(function(x) return article.description.contains(x)) Then
    ... do something
End if
```

We can also create a single expression to pass to `Any` and can use `ForEach` to enumerate the list:

```
    Dim ArticlesList As New List(Of Article)
    ArticlesList.ForEach(
        Sub(article)
            Dim Matcher = Function(x)
                              Return article.description.Contains(x)
                          End Function
            If {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string8"}.Any(Matcher) Then
                'Do something
            End If
            If {"string4", "string3", "string9"}.Any(Matcher) Then
                'Do something
            End If
        End Sub)
```

You could get creative and create a list of string arrays you want to search along side a list of delegates to invoke when a match is found:

```
Public Class CallBack
    Public IsMatch As Func(Of String, Boolean)
    Public CallBack = Sub() End
End Class
Public Shared Sub DoSomething()
    Console.WriteLine("did something")
End Sub
Public Shared Sub DoSomethingElse()
    Console.WriteLine("did something else")
End Sub
Public Shared Sub DoEvenSomethingElse()
    Console.WriteLine("did even something else")
End Sub
Public Sub FindMatches2()

    Dim CallBacks As New List(Of CallBack)(
    {
         New CallBack With
         {
            .IsMatch = Function(a) (a.Contains("string1") Or a.Contains("string2")) And a.Contains("string9"),
            .Routine = Sub() DoSomething()
    },
         New CallBack With
         {
            .IsMatch = Function(a) a.Contains("string1") Or (a.Contains("string2") And a.Contains("string8")),
            .Routine = Sub() DoSomething()
         }
    }
    )

    Dim ArticleList As New List(Of Article)
    ArticleList.Add(New Article() With {.description = "string1"})


    ArticleList.ForEach(
        Sub(article)
            CallBacks.ForEach(
            Sub(matcher)
                If matcher.IsMatch(article.description) Then
                    Dim result = matcher.Routine
                End If
            End Sub
            )
        End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: this is a very good approach in my opinion. only a thing: if I understand, the function in .Any returns true if almost one of the strings is contained, but if I need to make a boolean expression more complex do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: You can add any conditions you want inside of `Function(x)`. If it really complicated define an actual function eg, `Public MyComplexFunction(x as string)` and change matcher to `Dim Matcher = MyComplexFunction`

Comment: thanks, but I'm still tring to understand. If I try the first If you've posted, it seems to recursively cycles every element of the array {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string8"}, with x assuming time to time the value of one of them. Until it doesn't find an x that is contained in article.description, it continues to return False and the condition in the If isn't done, but at the first True it matches, so when it finds the first string in the array contained in article.description, it breaks every control and execute the If condition.

Comment: if my need is to control, as example, if (("string1" OR "string2") AND "string9") are contained with these boolean conditions, how would I write this rule? can't figure out it.

Comment: I mean write the condition in the function(x). The only way I can think of is:

If ({"string1", "string2"}.Any(Function(x)(...)) AND {"string9"}.Any(Function(x)(...))) Then
'do something

but it would be like use .Any instead of the OR operator I think.

Comment: All you have to do is change the signature of your the match function. I updated the code to show you how.